# android studio support plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using Android Studio 4.1.3, but I get this error when I run the Jetcaster project (one of the examples of Google code).

`This version of the Android Support plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio) cannot open this project, please retry with version 2020.3.1 or newer.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently need a Canary version of Android Studio to open Jetpack Compose projects.

https://developer.android.com/studio/preview